# Pandas ydata-profiling

Tags: python, pandas, profiling

I’m using ydata-profiling to profile a data set then I’m converting it to html using pandas to_html() this was working fine and all of a sudden it’s giving an error
“TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected ‘end of statement block’”

I checked to_json and it’s working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to use ".to_file('your_report.html')"?
It should work, maybe there have been some changes in latest versions.

(If you need help from developer of ydata-profling, you can use the tag "pandas-profling" for your requests)

Simone

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same issue. Working on databricks with pandas dataframe.

ydata-profiling==4.6.1
pandas==2.1.2

edit: my problems are solved in the latest version 4.6.3

Comment: using the .to_file('your_report.html')